# TestNG combine method threadCount and dataProviderThreadCount

Tags: java, maven, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm using the maven-failsafe-plugin to run testNG tests. It has `threadCount` configuration for methods and also `dataproviderthreadcount` property. Tests are run on physical devices, so `threadCount * dataproviderthreadcount` can't exceed the number of devices I have. When tests without data provider are run, I underutilize my resources. Can the number of thread counts be set for both method and data provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this if you use the latest released version of TestNG viz., `7.9.0`

This version of TestNG provides two new attributes for controlling the thread pool size.

Quoting the documentation

- `use-global-thread-pool` - When this attribute is set to true at the suite level, TestNG will start using a common thread pool for running both your regular test methods and data driven test methods. The size of the thread pool is determined using the attribute thread-count. This attribute has a default value of `false`.
- `share-thread-pool-for-data-providers` - When this attribute is set to true at the suite level, TestNG will start using a shared thread pool for all the data driven tests in a given `<suite>`. The size of the thread pool is determined using the attribute `data-provider-thread-count`. This attribute has a default value of `false`.

More details are available at https://testng.org/#_controlling_threadpool_usage